# Linux script - password step cuts the flow

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, command

Lets assume the script i want to write ssh to 1.2.3.4 and then invokes
ls. 
The problem is that when the line "ssh 1.2.3.4" is invoked, a password is
Required, hence, the flow is stopped, even when i fill the password,
The script wont continue. 
How can i make the script continue after the password is given?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're trying to run ls locally but you have an ssh session opened. So it won't run ls until the session is opened. If you want to run ls remotely, you should use

`ssh username@host COMMAND`

Where command is the command you want to run. Ssh session will finish as soon as the command is invoked and you can capture its output normally.

I would suggest you to use RSA authentication method for script that needs ssh.

I just tried this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh vps1 ls
mkdir temp
cd temp
echo test > file.txt
```

And it works. I can connect to my server and list my home. Then, locally, it creates temp dir, cd into it and then creates file.txt with 'test' inside.

Comment: After invoking such line, when it finishes, the script doesn't continue. (i want to continue doing stuff on my side)

Comment: Added and example. I have tried it both with RSA auth and password auth and it works perfectly. Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do public key authentication.  Here are some resources which should get you going.

http://magicmonster.com/kb/net/ssh/auto_login.html

http://www.cs.rpi.edu/research/groups/vision/doc/auto/ssh/ssh_public_key_authentication.html

I would post a couple more links, but I don't have enough reputation points.  ;)  Just google on "SSH automated login" or "SSH public key authentication" if you need more help.

Comment: He can do it without, although it's suggested to use it.

Answer (score 0):

write simple login bash script named login_to and give exec permissions (chmod 744 login_to)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 = 'srv1' ]; then
  echo 'srv1-pass' | pbcopy
  ssh root@11.11.11.11
fi

if [ $1 = 'foo' ]; then
  echo 'barbaz' | pbcopy
  ssh -t dux@22.22.22.22 'cd ~/somedir/someotherdir; bash'
fi
```

now use it like this

login_to srv1

login_to foo

When asked for password, just pate (ctrl+v or command+v) and you will be logged in.